# How to read csv file into pandas DataFrame with multiple row index level?

Tags: python, pandas

The original csv file data is like that:

```
06/04/2011,104.64,105.17
07/04/2011,104.98,105.51
08/04/2011,105.43,105.96
11/04/2011,104.47,104.99
```

How to either read the csv file into DataFrame and add multiple row index level, or add multiple row index into csv and import into DataFrame as following:

```
                JAS
      date      bid    ask
06/04/2011   104.64 105.17
07/04/2011   104.98 105.51
08/04/2011   105.43 105.96
11/04/2011   104.47 104.99
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the CSV, setting the first (0th) columns as the index.

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""06/04/2011,104.64,105.17
07/04/2011,104.98,105.51
08/04/2011,105.43,105.96
11/04/2011,104.47,104.99"""), index_col=0, header=None)
```

Create a new MultiIndex, and assign it to the columns.

```
In [11]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('JAS', 'bid'), ('JAS', 'ask')])
```

Finally, name the index, and we have your desired result.

```
In [12]: df.index.name = 'date'

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
               JAS        
               bid     ask
date                      
06/04/2011  104.64  105.17
07/04/2011  104.98  105.51
08/04/2011  105.43  105.96
11/04/2011  104.47  104.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0, header=None).rename_axis(
index='date').rename(columns={1: 'bid', 2: 'ask'}).reindex(
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['JAS'], ['bid', 'ask']]), level=1)

Out[1]: 
           JAS        
           bid     ask
date                      
2011-06-04  104.64  105.17
2011-07-04  104.98  105.51
2011-08-04  105.43  105.96
2011-11-04  104.47  104.99
```